# Chained animation with a list of views RxJava2 Android

Tags: android, animation, rx-java, android-animation, rx-java2

everyone! I'm having issues with RxJava2 to set a list of views and animate one after the other (once each view finishes its animation).

I did lots of researches and the only thing close to that using RxJava2 is using the "`andThen()`" operator with the `Completable` class which is not what I'm looking for.

My main idea is to have a:

```
Observable<List<View>> observable = Observable.fromArray(listOfViews);
```

and emit single `View` to animate, wait for the animation to finish and move to the next one.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve: [Animation example](https://pspdfkit.com/images/blog/2016/android-animations-powered-by-rx-java/gif1-6a6dc049.gif)

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

It's not the solution I'm looking for, but I manage to make one version using `delay` but the idea is: waiting for the animation to finish and then move to the next `onNext`

My solution so far:

```
List<View> listOfViews = new ArrayList<>();
listOfViews.add(buttonOne);
listOfViews.add(buttonTwo);
listOfViews.add(buttonThree);

Observable
       .fromIterable(listOfViews)
       .concatMap(view -> Observable.just(view)
               .delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
               .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
               .doOnNext(item -> item.animate()
                       .scaleX(2)
                       .scaleY(2)
                       .setDuration(1000)
                       .start()))
       .toList()
       .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want each animation to begin after the last one completes, you are right that a solution is to use Completables, example:

```
// Assuming you have a source of views to animate
Observable<View> views = Observable.just(button1, button2, button3);

// Create a Completable that completes when the animation ends
public Completable animateView(View view) {
    return Completable
             .create(emitter -> {
                  Animation animation = view.animate();
                  emitter.setCancellable(() -> animation.cancel());
                  animation
                      .scaleX(2f)
                      .scaleY(2f)
                      .setDuration(1000)
                      .withEndAction(() -> emitter.onComplete())
                      .start();
             });
}

// Execute each animation sequentially
views
    .concatMapCompletable(v -> animateView(v))
    .subscribe(...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I updated my question including one of the version I came with... but I really need to each ViewPropertyAnimator to finish using withEndAction()

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla no problem! now that I see your animation implementation I have updated the answer. I hope this helps.